# Screen recording on mac using C++

Tags: c++, screen-recording

What is the best way to record a user's screen in C++? I have been goggling this topic lately and I can't find any good articles/tutorials.

Is it possible to screen record on mac using C++? If so, how can I do so? Thank you.

Comment: Your questions are far too broad and answers are likely to be based mostly on opinion.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I am just trying to find out if you can screen record on mac using C++, and how to do so.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious This question is a bit broad, but OK for StackOverflow. It's asking how to perform a specific task, which is hard to search for in the API docs if you don't know the function name. No opinion needed in my answer either.

Comment: @NicholasWilson: No, it's too broad for Stack Overflow. The brevity and vagueness of your answer demonstrates that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `CGDisplayStream` API. Unfortunately, it's not all that well documented, but there are some good samples available on the Apple website and if you search for it on Github.

Comment: Thank you, I am looking into it right now. I also found this: [http://www.uri-labs.com/header10.9/CGDisplayStream_h/index.html](http://www.uri-labs.com/header10.9/CGDisplayStream_h/index.html)

Comment: Try https://github.com/DouglasHeriot/PresenterMirror